# I need to find regular expression to find a string

Tags: php, regex, netbeans

I've created a regular expression: `^\\[(.*)\\]$`

to find all strings [....] eg. [general]

and I need to replace it with ['general']

but it is not working

in Netbeans php also I need lowercase like general_offline

Thanks

Comment: in Netbeans php also I need lowercase like general_offline

Answer (score 1):

I see two things that would probably make problems

1. You used the anchors `^` and `$`. they match the start and the end of the string, if you are searching inside a larger text it will not find them. If so, just remove them:

   ```
   \\[(.*)\\]
   ```
2. `.*` is greedy. That means `\\[(.*)\\]` will match from the frist opening `[` to the last closing `]`. If so add a `?` after the quantifier to change the matching behaviour to "lazy".

   ```
   \\[(.*?)\\]
   ```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32dcg)

Comment: for some reason netbeans do not highlide results: \\[(.*)\\] and make regular expression red :(

Answer (score 0):

Strange this one works: `(\[.*])` almost because I need to find inside without [ ]